# How to get minimum unused number from a column in Oracle and Linq?

Tags: oracle, linq

I have a column named voucher_number. The data in this column looks like 
1, 2

I want a query (in oracle and linq as well) to return 0,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
Note: i am taking range (0 to 10 )as a parameter parameter from  screen(aspx page)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code thus you can get better answer.

Comment: right now i have tried this in  oracle********
WITH data AS (select vm_no , vm_deleted,vm_year,  vm_co_code,vm_per from gl_vchrmaster 
where vm_vchr_type ='JV' 
and to_number(vm_no)  between 0 and 10
and VM_PER  = 5--NOV
and vm_year='2019'
and vm_co_code='0001' )

-- request:
SELECT  COALESCE(MIN(d1.vm_no+1),1) as vm_no
  FROM data d1 LEFT JOIN data d2 ON d1.vm_no+1 = d2.vm_no 
  WHERE d2.vm_no IS NULL
 ;

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MINUS` operator as following:

```
Select voucher_num from
(
(Select level - 1 as voucher_num from dual
Connect by level <= 11)
Minus
(Select voucher_number from your_table)
)
Order by voucher_num;
```

Cheers!!